# creating dynamic link in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to generate dynamic link using object id property

trying to generate link like this /news/details/5

I'm getting object in my view as `$rec`, so I tried like

```
<a href="/news/details/<?=$rec->id;?> ">more info</a>
```

but I'm getting error.

Comment: actually, error is not thrown, but link is created without id, just /news/details

Comment: Do `var_dump($rec->id);`

Comment: I think we'd benefit from seeing more code, and details about `$rec`.

Comment: are you sure rec is an object... try to print_r($rec);  more likely then not your $rec is an array and it should be `<?= $rec["id"]; ?>`

Comment: nope, I'm positive for object property, fetching all the other properties, title, content, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following if `$rec` is a primitive variable which holds your id:

```
<?php 
  $rec = 5; // or any other value, maybe from database, too
?>
<a href="/news/details/<?php echo $rec; ?>">more info</a>
```

i hope i could help :)

Comment: that;s what I'm talking about :)